# Laravel (Skote install) on WAMP - HTTP methods GET unsupported

Tags: php, laravel, httprequest, apache2.4, wamp64

I am in the process of setting up a local version of the Laravel Skote template (https://themeforest.net/item/skote-html-laravel-admin-dashboard-template/25548061) on a **WAMP64 server** on my Windows machine (following these instructions https://themesbrand.com/skote/docs/setup-laravel.html), and upon install I am I am presented with an **HTTP error**:

"**The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: HEAD.**"

[image]

[image]

I have found other questions related to this, but in each case the proposed answers relate to the type of request set in the Controller and code itself, and not addressing the server setup in any way.

I tested the exact install on a live test server (DigitalOcean Debian 10) and the install works absolutely fine. For this reason I believe it is a setting within WAMP itself to enable **GET/POST/PUT/DELETE** http methods, and not something that should need changing in any route settings in the Laravel files.

Can anyone please help on how to enable this on WAMP. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's connected with your WAMP because the message about not supported GET method is from Laravel (so Apache allowed that request and then Laravel catched it [Symfony component in fact]).

Run `php artisan route:list` and check if the route that you want to access works for GET method.

Comment: Thanks @Pawel Ploka. I ran that command and got the following: https://imgur.com/lQe3YSu. I think Login is the first page to show - sorry new to Laravel so unsure on the exact order of the route throwing the error